# How to combine ontologies?

Tags: ontology

I am a beginner in the field of ontologies, ontology alignment and composition of ontologies. What is the purpose of the composition of ontologies and on what basis it is performed and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the main advantages of using ontologies is knowledge sharing. Different people from various backgrounds might develop the same ontology. This will often result in having different labels for the same concepts or relations. In order to be able to take advantage of having multiple ontologies in the same domain, for example for having a more comprehensive and expressive domain ontology, ontology matching/alignment comes to play. In the ontology matching, a mapping between concepts an relations of various ontologies is created.

For example, before [national cancer institute](http://www.cancer.gov/cancertopics/cancerlibrary/terminologyresources) came up with the first version of their cancer ontology, there were multiple ontologies modelling cancer around. They started by combining the various available ontologies and creating a central, more reliable ontology.

There are various algorithms for ontology matching. The algorithms normally are categorised based on:

- input
- process
- output

Broadly putting it, you can either match on element to element basis, or based on the structure. The tools that can be used for matching can be linguistic resources such as WordNet for semantic matching, or domain specific resources, statistical approaches, taxonomy, various models, and etc.There are too much research in this area and you should really consider using google scholar.

Comment: thank you for answer.
as I said before, I am a beginner in the field, I started reading the book of ontology matching (euzenat & Shvaiko) but I can't distinguish between the matching approaches and matching tools !! can you help me with this if possible giving me a list of approaches and another for tools?

Comment: The people that you have mentioned have the best survey out there. I think you need to identify which approach for matching you want to follow and then dig deeper. There is also a current review from couple of months ago. "Ontology matching: A literature review", see if this helps. But to able o know all he algorithms you need to do a PhD in it!

Comment: if we want to choose an approach and a tool, on what criteria is made that choice? is the matching strategy (mentionned in the book) means  "approache" (e.g. partitionning, matching composition, matching learning,...)? Cupid, similarity flooding, Hcone, HSM, CBW,... are tools or approaches ?

Comment: The ones you mentioned are approaches, tools are the way you actually implement it. Read the main book. I think it is a fantastic one. You might want to consider ontology Evolution as well. At some point they tie in together.